# Interpret SVC and GridSearch results

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, svm, grid-search

I am working on a texture classifier using [scikit-learn svm svc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC) as a model. I am a bit confused about some of the results I get, mainly why the choices of parameters *gamma* and *C* have such a big influence on my results. So here is a short description of my case:

In total I have 195 images divided into 8 classes as follows; wood - 56, marble - 23, cement - 16, concrete - 7, tile - 32, carpet - 18, brick - 25, fabric - 18.

I randomly divide my data into training and test set by a 80-20 ratio.

I use SVC as a model: `model = SVC(C=C, random_state=42, gamma=gamma)`

I fit my model with the training data. Next I predict classes for my test data and use accuracy (ratio of correct predictions) as a score.

For different choices of *C* and *gamma* my score looks as follows:

For *C=100* and varying *gamma*:

`| gamma | 1e-3|1e-2|1e-1| 1e0| 1e1| 1e2| 1e3| 1e4|
| score  | 0.28|0.28|0.29|0.36|0.54|0.76|1.00|1.00|`

And for fixed *gamma=10* and varying *C*

`| C      |1e-1| 1e0| 1e1| 1e2| 1e3| 1e4| 1e5| 1e6|
| score  | 0.28|0.29|0.37|0.54|0.67|0.83|0.97|1.00|`

As seen the score increases as both *C* and *gamma* increases.

First of all, I think the result for large *C* and *gamma* is too 'perfect'. It has a 100% accuracy. As I understand the influence of *C*, the larger the *C* the more exactly does it fit the train data, but the less 'smooth' is the model. I guess you could interpret the result as train and test data being very similiar, and therefore a large value of *C* will result in a large accuracy. If we consider *gamma* as the inverse influencial radius of each train item, it too concludes that the train and test data might be very similiar.

On the other hand, when I use `GridSearchCV` to tune the parameters, I get the result:

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qycfq.png)

The best `The best parameters are {'C': 100000.0, 'gamma': 10.0} with a score of 0.46`

How can I interpret this score of 0.46? To me it seems very low compared to the accuracy result I got when I tested.